# Unable to find the regex for this pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

For a dotnet application, I have a string pattern as shown below:

```
TEAM AND CO TEAM
TESTER
Name anderson rahul alice
```

and I need to only capture the value of "Name", but the value of name will be captured only when the string sequence will be "TEAM AND CO TEAM" is in one line and "TESTER" in next line and "Name" appearing on the next to next line.

Below is my regex but it is also selecting the second occurance of the Name, which I do not require :

```
\bName\s+(.*)$
```

input string  :

```
TEAM AND CO TEAM
TESTER
Name anderson rahul alice

LTest SYNC DIM TESTER
PHYSICS
Name KIM SID andy
```

any help would be appreciable.

[Screenshot of the regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Cna.png)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```cs
(?m)(?<=^TEAM AND CO TEAM\r?\nTESTER\r?\nName\s).+
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5ETEAM%20AND%20CO%20TEAM%5Cr%3F%5CnTESTER%5Cr%3F%5CnName%5Cs%29.%2B&i=TEAM%20AND%20CO%20TEAM%0D%0ATESTER%0D%0AName%20anderson%20rahul%20alice%0D%0A%0D%0ALTest%20SYNC%20DIM%20TESTER%0D%0APHYSICS%0D%0AName%20KIM%20SID%20andy).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TEAM AND CO TEAM         'TEAM AND CO TEAM'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TESTER                   'TESTER'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Name                     'Name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `\bName\s+(.*)$` you are only matching `Name` and then capture  the rest of the line after matching 1 or more whitespace characters.

You can extend the pattern to match the required line `TEAM AND CO TEAM` and `TESTER` in the next line.

Then match `Name` and capture the value that you want in group 1.

Note to enable the multiline flag.

```
^TEAM AND CO TEAM\r?\nTESTER\r?\nName\s(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `TEAM AND CO TEAM\r?\n` Match `TEAM AND CO TEAM`, an optional carriage return and a newline
- `TESTER\r?\n` Match `TESTER`, an optional carriage return and a newline
- `Name\s` Match `Name` and a whitespace character
- `(.+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more chars which will match the rest of the line

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eTEAM+AND+CO+TEAM%5cr%3f%5cnTESTER%5cr%3f%5cnName%5cs%28.%2b%29&i=TEAM+AND+CO+TEAM%0d%0aTESTER%0d%0aName+anderson+rahul+alice%0d%0a%0d%0aLTest+SYNC+DIM+TESTER%0d%0aPHYSICS%0d%0aName+KIM+SID+andy%0d%0a&o=m)

[image]